# How can I use WHERE with JOIN LEFT?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql request, that is working fine:

```
$pdo = $db->query('
SELECT *, 
GROUP_CONCAT(cat.name SEPARATOR " <br> ") AS dog, 
monkey.id AS id, 
duck.id AS horse_id, 
bird.id AS elephant_id
FROM monkey
LEFT JOIN duck ON monkey.horse=duck.id 
LEFT JOIN bird ON monkey.elephant=bird.id
LEFT JOIN cat ON monkey.id=cat.mouse_id 
GROUP BY monkey.id ASC;');
```

But now I want to select only the values where monkey = "id".

So I tried to make this solution:

```
 $pdo = $db->query('
    SELECT *, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(cat.name SEPARATOR " <br> ") AS dog, 
    monkey.id AS id, 
    duck.id AS horse_id, 
    bird.id AS elephant_id
    FROM monkey WHERE id = "'.$id.'"
    LEFT JOIN duck ON monkey.horse=duck.id 
    LEFT JOIN bird ON monkey.elephant=bird.id
    LEFT JOIN cat ON monkey.id=cat.mouse_id 
    GROUP BY monkey.id ASC;');
```

But I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN duck ON monkey.chorse=duck.id LEFT JOIN
>   bird ON monkey.bir' at line 7 in ..mypage.php:28 Stack trace: #0
>   ..mypage.php(28): PDO->query('\nSELECT *, \nGRO...') #1 {main} thrown
>   in ...mypage.php on line 28

Comment: When in doubt, check [the syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html). There's a particular order to the select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must make the `joins` and then the `where`,try this:

```
 $pdo = $db->query('
    SELECT *, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(cat.name SEPARATOR " <br> ") AS dog, 
    monkey.id AS id, 
    duck.id AS horse_id, 
    bird.id AS elephant_id
    FROM monkey
    LEFT JOIN duck ON monkey.horse=duck.id 
    LEFT JOIN bird ON monkey.elephant=bird.id
    LEFT JOIN cat ON monkey.id=cat.mouse_id 
    WHERE monkey.id = "'.$id.'"
    GROUP BY monkey.id ASC;');
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you have a couple of problems. First you're not sanitizing your `id` (look up Bobby Tables). Second, you put the `WHERE` clause in the wrong place, and third you're not telling SQL which ID column to use.

Follow this as a general pattern:

```
SELECT
  <table1>.<column1>,
  <table2>.<column2>,
  (etc)
FROM
  <table1>
  JOIN
     <table>
     ON (<table1>.<id-column> = <table2>.<id-column)
WHERE
   <table1>.<id-column> = ${id-value}
```

In your case,

```
$query = 'SELECT *, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(cat.name SEPARATOR " <br> ") AS dog, 
    monkey.id AS id, 
    duck.id AS horse_id, 
    bird.id AS elephant_id
FROM monkey 
    LEFT JOIN duck ON monkey.horse=duck.id 
    LEFT JOIN bird ON monkey.elephant=bird.id
    LEFT JOIN cat ON monkey.id=cat.mouse_id 
WHERE monkey.id = "'.$db->escape($id).'"
GROUP BY monkey.id ASC';
```

Comment: I have no idea if `db->escape` is what you need, but you need to escape that valie.

Comment: @Jarla The problem is that without the escape you are likely to experience SQL injection. I suggest you look it up.